# Where are the headers for libbz2.dylib for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, compression, header

The headers for libbz2.dylib on the iPhone are missing, or contained in a less than obvious location.  I've looked for bzlib.h, bz2lib.h, bz2.h, etc., grepped for patterns, and found nothing - are they included with the SDK, or do I need to just pull the header from the main libbz2 distro and use that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the library is clearly available on the device, the header really should be in the SDK, but it appears that it isn't. I'd use the one that's packaged for the Simulator, since this is most likely to be the same as the one on the device:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.2.1.sdk/usr/include/bzlib.h
```

Then open a [Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com/) case to ask that the distribution be fixed.

Comment: Ah, didn't check the Simulator directories - thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

From the site below get the bzlib-0.5.0.0.tar.gz file and copy the files (.h and .c) inside the cbits directory to your Xcode project.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bzlib

So far it seems to work, I've managed to read the contents of a .bz2 file with the functions BZ2_bzReadOpen and then BZ2_bzRead.